# jQuery ajax GeoJson coordsToLatLngs data returning - Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, ...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet, geojson

So I am trying to flip my coordinates so my polygon of country borders on my map aren't stretched vertically across my map.

My border polygons appear but incorrectly. So I implemented Leaflet's coordsToLatLngs function and I'm getting Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, -77.53466,23.75975,-77.78,23.71,-78.03405,24.28615,-78.40848,24.57564,-78.19087,25.2103,-77.89,25.17,-77.54,24.34,-77.53466,23.75975)

Not sure what the undefined could be pointing to?

Thank you guys.

Here is my code

// add borders to countries

```
$.ajax({
  url: "libs/php/mapCountries.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",

  success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);

    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      var latlng = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(result.data[i].geometry.coordinates, 0, false);
      var polygon = L.polygon(result.data[i].geometry.coordinates, { color: "red" }).addTo(map);

      // zoom the map to the polygon
      map.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds());
    }
    var coords = console.log(result);
  },
});
```

Here is my JSON decoded from my PHP file

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Bahamas",
        "iso_a2": "BS",
        "iso_a3": "BHS",
        "iso_n3": "044"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [-77.53466, 23.75975],
              [-77.78, 23.71],
              [-78.03405, 24.28615],
              [-78.40848, 24.57564],
              [-78.19087, 25.2103],
              [-77.89, 25.17],
              [-77.54, 24.34],
              [-77.53466, 23.75975]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [-77.82, 26.58],
              [-78.91, 26.42],
              [-78.98, 26.79],
              [-78.51, 26.87],
              [-77.85, 26.84],
              [-77.82, 26.58]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [-77, 26.59],
              [-77.17255, 25.87918],
              [-77.35641, 26.00735],
              [-77.34, 26.53],
              [-77.78802, 26.92516],
              [-77.79, 27.04],
              [-77, 26.59]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That looks like properly formatted GeoJSON. It's gonna be easier to `var polygon = L.geoJson(result.data[i])`.

Comment: Hey Ivan, yes this was the correct way to go about it! I tried to overcomplicate it all! Thank you for your response